# Process Hive Query with Collection Types in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I have the following query:

`Select * from MyNode`

How can I process the row in spark where the column is a MAP to get the Key and its value?

Hive Table Schema

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyNode
(
    Name STRING,
    CommandText MAP <TINYINT, STRING> ,
    )
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
    COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
    MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY ':'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
   STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/MyNode'
```

1 Row of Data

```
MYNODENAME|{1:"echo",2:"mkdir",3:"cp"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "process the row" exactly?  What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: 'List<Row> results = hiveContext.sql("select Name, CommandText from MyNode").collect();
if (results.size() > 0) {
   for(Row r: results){
    //class java.lang.String
    String nodeName = r.getString(0);
    //class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaUtils$SerializableMapWrapper
    How can I extract the columns data from MAP <TINYINT, STRING>
    }'

Comment: How can I extract the columns data from MAP <TINYINT, STRING> in spark?

Comment: @MurphyRic Did you get the answer for this? I am in same condition where i want to parse the data from map column in table